# Python - Get total distance from GPS longitude and latitude

Tags: python, python-3.x, gps, coordinates

I don't know what the heck is wrong with this, but I can't figure it out at all.

So I have this code:

```
from model.Formulas import Formulas

f = open("coords_data.txt", "r")
line1 = f.readline()
line2 = f.readline()

orig = line1.split(';')
dest = line2.split(';')

origin = (orig[0] + ", " + orig[1].strip("\n"))
destination = (dest[0] + ", " + dest[1].strip("\n"))

print("Orig: " + str(origin))
print("Dest: " + str(destination))

total_dist = Formulas.calculateDistance(str(origin), str(destination))

# Formulas.calculateDistance()
```

And then the import code is this:

```
import math

class Formulas:
    # 3959  # radius of the great circle in miles...some algorithms use 3956
    # 6371  # radius in kilometers...some algorithms use 6367
    # 3959 * 5280  # radius in feet
    # 6371 * 1000  # radius in meters
    @staticmethod
    def calculateDistance(origin, destination, rounding=0):
        lat1, lon1 = origin
        lat2, lon2 = destination
        radius = 6371  # km

        dlat = math.radians(lat2 - lat1)
        dlon = math.radians(lon2 - lon1)
        a = math.sin(dlat / 2) * math.sin(dlat / 2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon / 2) * math.sin(dlon / 2)
        c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
        d = radius * c
        return round(d, rounding)
```

So now I want to get from a large list (5057 lines) of coordinates to have the exact total distance. So it needs to count all differences between the distances and return one large number (for example 150km).

The error I get is:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

The coordinates in the file look like this:

```
5114.8268;00457.9847
5114.8271;00457.9845
5114.8271;00457.9845
5114.8271;00457.9845
5114.8270;00457.9846
5114.8271;00457.9846
5114.8272;00457.9847
5114.8272;00457.9847
5114.8274;00457.9843
5114.8272;00457.9846
5114.8274;00457.9843
5114.8277;00457.9837
5114.8287;00457.9835
5114.8274;00457.9843
5114.8288;00457.9831
5114.8287;00457.9835
5114.8286;00457.9813
5114.8274;00457.9843
5114.8287;00457.9815
5114.8286;00457.9813
5114.8270;00457.9846
5114.8286;00457.9813
5114.8355;00457.9784
5114.8292;00457.9814
5114.8274;00457.9843
5114.8376;00457.9776
5114.8395;00457.9769
```

It's now in a file, but this data will be stored in a database.

How can I fix this?  And how should I get rid of the error?

Comment: What error? could you give some simple examples of inputs / outputs vs expected outputs.

Comment: Updated. Sorry, forgot to place the error.

Answer (score 3):

`Formulas.calculateDistance()` expects tuples of floats:

**Try This:**

```
line1 = "5114.8268;00457.9847"
line2 = "5114.8271;00457.9845"

def strip_line(line_str):
    x, y = line_str.split(';')
    return float(x), float(y.strip())

total_dist = Formulas.calculateDistance(
    strip_line(line1), strip_line(line2))
```

The function `strip_line()` uses the same basic logic you are using, but wraps the logic up in a function, and most importantly, keeps the values as floats.

Comment: answered 24 secs ago. Damn, my editor was slow to start up.

Comment: Okej, So that works, but how can I loop trugh all values? So it will always work and give me the correct distance?